# Using the solution to an equation as an integral limit (when plotting)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to use the solution $r_0$ of the equation

$r^3 -r b^2 +2b^2=0$

as the limit of the integral

$\int^{r_0}_0 \left[b-b^3 u^3+\frac{b^3 u^2}{2}+\left(\frac{3 b^5}{8}+\frac{2 b^3}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) u^4 \right] du$

and plot this between $b=5$ and $b=10$.

I tried to use

```
Plot[Integrate[ b + 1/2 b^3 u^2-b^3 u^3 + (3/8 b^5 + (2  b^3)/Sqrt[\[ Pi]]) 
u^4, {u, 0,  Evaluate[ NSolve[r^3 == b^2 (r - 2), r, Reals]}]],{b,5,10}]
```

and

```
Subscript[r, 0][b_] = NSolve[r^3 == b^2 (r - 2), r, Reals]

Plot[Integrate[b + 1/2  b^3 u^2 - b^3 u^3 + (3/8  b^5 + 
(2b^3)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]) u^4, {u, 0, Evaluate[Subscript[r, 0][b]}]], {b, 5, 10}]
```

but these both give me a blank graph

Comment: There are several mistakes. 1. if you want to evaluate the expression before plotting, you should apply `Evaluate` on it. 2. The integration interval of `Integrate` should be a number or a symbol, but what `NSolve` returns is clearly not.

Comment: Thanks, so what should I do to NSolve? Should I apply Evaluate to NSolve? That doesn't seem to help

Comment: Well I meant the `Evaluate` should be before `Integrate` not `NSolve`...

Comment: Ok, so how should I get NSolve to give a number?

Comment: Which root are you looking for? Between $3\sqrt{3}$ and $10$, all three are real.

Comment: I want to use the smallest root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to pile up everything together. Have clarity with function definitions - what depends on what? Check that every part works separately.

```
bfun[b_] = First[r /. Solve[r^3 == b^2 (r - 2), r, Reals]];

abfun[a_, b_] = Integrate[b + (b^3 u^2)/2 - b^3 u^3 + 
((3 b^5)/8 + (2 b^3)/Sqrt[Pi]) u^4, {u, 0, a}];

Plot[abfun[bfun[b], b], {b, 5, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]